# PHP's preg_match() to match characters at the end of a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have the below *if* statement, and it never returns True. What is wrong?

I am new to PHP and regular expressions.

```
$String = '123456';
$Pattern = "/\d{2}$/";

// I intend to match '56', which are the last two digits of the string.

if(preg_match($Pattern $String, $matches))
{
    echo 'Matched';
}
```

If the `$Pattern` is `"/^\d{2}/"`, true is returned and matched the number '12';

---

My mistake. The above code works well.

In the actual code, the $String is assigned from a variable and it always end up with a dot which I was unaware of.

The requirement to match the last two digits above is just for issue explanation. The expression is required in actual code.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, your code seems to work fine for me? http://codepad.viper-7.com/xDhzmN

Comment: you don't need a regex to get the last two chars of a string. Please clarify what you want to do the last sentence of the question is hard to understand.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are correct.

```
$String = '123456';
$Pattern = "/\d{2}$/";
$Pattern2 = "/^\d{2}/";

if(preg_match($Pattern, $String, $matches))
{
    print_r($matches); // 56
}

if(preg_match($Pattern2, $String, $matches))
{
    print_r($matches); // 12
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your confirmation. I rechecked and find out is my mistake. I will take your answer.